# Jquery IE8 div contents showing before slidedown() complete?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, slidedown

Hopefully basic question! I have a standard jquery slidedown div, with three buttons inside it. When hovered, the div slides down in the usual way to reveal the links. All fine in FF / Safari, but in IE8 the content is shown as the div is sliding open giving a really nasty effect. The demo page is at http://james-golding.co.uk/staging/quocms/?page_id=29.

The jquery is pretty simple:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

          $(document).ready(function() 

          {ShowActionOnOver();

                $(".expandingbox",this).hide(); // hide all 
                $(".insidered",this).slideDown(500);

          });

function ShowActionOnOver()

        {$(".content").hover(function(){
                  if( $(".insidered").is(":visible") ) { $(".insidered").slideUp(500); }
                  $(".expandingbox",this).slideDown(500);

              },

              function()

              {$(".expandingbox",this).slideUp(500); }

            );}
```

CSS is also standard for this sort of thing:

```
.content {height:120px;}
.rel {z-index: inherit; zoom: 1; /* For IE6 */ position:relative; }

.expandingbox {
    width: 210px;
    height:100px;
    margin: 0 auto 0px auto;
    padding: 7px 6px 0px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    behavior: url(PIE.php);
    overflow : hidden;
}

.insidered {border: 2px solid #b60000;}

.steps {
    width: 195px;
    height: 13px;
    margin: 0px auto 3px auto;
    padding: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 11px ;
    -webkit-border-radius: 11px;
    border-radius: 11px;
    behavior: url(PIE.php);
    }

.stepslast {
    width: 195px;
    height: 13px;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    padding: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 11px ;
    -webkit-border-radius: 11px;
    border-radius: 11px;
    behavior: url(PIE.php);
}

.label {
    width: 101px;
    height: 17px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 8px 0  5px 0;
     -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 11px 11px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 11px 11px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 11px 11px;
    behavior: url(PIE.php);
    color:#FFFFFF;

}
```

I would appreciate any thoughts on this - it's driving me nuts!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This does the the trick: `.expandingbox insidered{overflow:hidden;}`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply but that's not made any difference for me, it's added in on the site but no change. I'll rebuild the css and see what's causing it.

Comment: It was my mistake - I'm using pie.htc for the rounded corners and that was giving it the flicker effect.  Thanks for the assist anyway. @stack101